# Designing an E-Commerce Database - MySQL

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, relational-database

I'm doing an e-commerce project and am confused about the database design for storing products. There are 3 ways I've speculated the database can be made:

1.
There can be separate tables for each product category.

```
Table: Categories
------------------
cat_ID
cat_name

Table: Sub_Categories
---------------------
sub_cat_ID
categories_cat_ID
sub_cat_name

Table: Books
-------------
book_ID
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
book_title
book_author
book_ISBN
book_price
etc

Table: Clothes
---------------
clothes_ID
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
clothes_name
clothes_color
clothes_size
clothes_description
clothes_price
etc

Table: Perfumes
----------------
perfumes_ID
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
perfume_name
perfume_size
perfume_weight
perfume_description
perfume_price
etc
```

2.
Group all products together in one table and allow some values to be null

```
Table: Categories
------------------
cat_ID
cat_name

Table: Sub_Categories
---------------------
sub_cat_ID
categories_cat_ID
sub_cat_name

Table: Products
---------------
product_ID
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
title
description
price
author (can be null for everything except books)
size
weight (can be null for everything except perfumes)
ISBN (can be null for everything except books)
color (can be null for everything except clothes)
etc
```

3.
Group similar column fields together in a table called products, and provide separate tables for specific data.

```
Table: Categories
------------------
cat_ID
cat_name

Table: Sub_Categories
---------------------
sub_cat_ID
categories_cat_ID
sub_cat_name

Table: Products
----------------
product_ID
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
title
description
price

Table: Books
-------------
products_product_id
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
author
publisher
ISBN

Table: Perfumes
----------------
products_product_id
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
size
weight

Table: Clothes
--------------
products_product_id
sub_categories_sub_cat_ID
color
size (this can be a one to many relationship to cater to multiple sizes of one product?)
```

I would really appreciate enlightenment, thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume a product can belong to many categories, and a category (obviously) has many products in it. This relationship is called a many-to-many relation.

In this instance, you would have three tables: `categories`, `products`, and `categories_products`. The first two tables are self-explanatory. The third table stores a relation between the two with two foreign keys. The tables would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `categories_products` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `categories_products`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_products_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_products_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Obviously these are the table schemas at their simplest. You will need to add your additional columns to the `categories` and `products` table—I’ve only included the columns relavant to the relation.

EDIT: I also added a `parent_id` column to the `categories` table for nesting categories. It’s generally a bad idea to create a separate `sub_categories` table—what happens if you want to make a sub-category a top-level category? Or vice versa? You’re buggered for want of a better phrase.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My main issue is how/where to store different data for different types of products. I.e. would you have a column for authors/ISBN/color/sizes/weight/etc all in the products table or would you separate them out to avoid null values?

Comment: I would have a base `products` table, and then maybe an `product_attributes` table for additional data like ISBN numbers, and not every product is going to have an ISBN number if it’s not a publication.

Comment: So method 3 would be the way to go (apart from the sub_categories table)? Or are you saying that every attribute for all products should be placed in the table product_attributes?

Comment: Pretty much. Although you don’t want to be creating a new table for each different type of product. It’s not scalable and hard to maintain.

Comment: I should store all unique data for each product under product_attributes with a foreign key to products_product_ID?

Comment: Yeah, you’d have a foreign key to the `product_id`, and then an attribute name and an attribute value.

Comment: Are you saying you can have key-value pairs in a table??

Comment: In a sense. Your attributes table would just be four columns: `id`, `product_id` (foreign key), `name`, and `value`. You can have multiple rows per product (one-to-many).

Comment: Oh I see, so I can say something like name = ISBN, value = 20903840? But wouldn't that make querying more complicated?

Comment: You may need a second query, but it’s how most e-commerce platforms like Magento, Prestashop et al will handle product attributes.

Comment: I'm just cautious as to whether I will have tons of unused if/foreach conditions hanging around in my code to check whether the product being requested by a user requires the color/weight/size/etc attributes to be returned. Also in the admin view, say I want to delete one size of a clothing item which has 5 or 6 different sizes attributed to it, what would I do then? Thank you for your time by the way

Comment: Just wondering why M-M between products and Categories. I think you want a product to belong to only one category only - I assume catalogs are designed this way. However, categories may be part of other categories.

Answer (score 10):

I think it depends on the products to use method 1 or 2. I would never use method 3.

If your products are completly different like Books, Perfumes and Clothes I would use method 1

One sidenote: Why use 2 tables for your catagories?
Use one table and add a column Parent_ID that way you can use unlimited subcatagories in the future.

for example:

```
table: categories

|id|description|parentid|
|1 |books      |NULL    |
|2 |clothes    |NULL    |
|3 |perfumes   |NULL    |
|4 |Sci-Fi     |1       |
|5 |Comedy     |1       |
|6 |Jeans      |2       |
|7 |Sweater    |2       |
|8 |Underwear  |2       |
|9 |Long sleeve|7       |
|10|Roses      |3       |
```

- Books, Clothes en Perfumes do not have a parent (those are the main
  categories).
- Sci-Fi and Comedy is a subcategory of Books (ID 1).
- Jeans, Sweater and Underwear is a subcategory of clothes (ID 2).
- Long Sleeve is a subcategory of Sweater (ID 7).
- Roses is a subcategory of perfumes (ID 3).

Comment: can u explain little further with example of parent id

Comment: Edited my answer with an example of parent id. I hope you understand what I have in mind

Comment: ooh buddy you know i am done with my site and i pass through complex ways i used method 1 to create my shopping cart oh luc why i wouldnt there before creation of my site i appreciated your effort and voting you thanks